# Typing backslash using Windows emulator on a Mac

Tags: windows, macos, keyboard

I am on a Mac (OS X Mavericks) running Windows 7 and wish to type a backslash to specify a path in the command line window. How do I do this using the Mac keyboard (UK)? (And how do I get other characters that map differently like the tilde?)

Comment: right side ALT key and the backslash key works for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm answering my own question because I couldn't find an answer that worked for me anywhere else and finally found it by accident. Thought it might help someone else.

First I should say that since posting I have tried an emulator on a Mac with a different keyboard (desktop rather than laptop) and discovered I didn't have the same problem with the backslash (although I did with other characters). So the answer will depend on the keyboard.

To get a backslash \ I found I could use the 'backtick' key (to the left of the Z on my Mac Keyboard) on both keyboards I tried (the backslash is in this position on a Windows keyboard).

As regards the tilde ~ (key to left of Z + shift on the Mac), I found that on one keyboard I could get it at the position of ± (shift on key to left of 1) whereas on the other keyboard it was in the position of the pipe (shift on key to extreme left of ASD row).

The other keys that mapped differently were " and the @, which were interchanged on one keyboard (corresponding to Windows mapping). # was also a problem on one keyboard, mapping to the \ (but US keyboards map # differently to UK keyboards.)

Comment: You might be able to fix this by an appropriate choice of keyboard layout.

Comment: Can change between US and UK layouts in Mac System prefs, but not to a Windows layout. Would have expected emulator software (VMWare Fusion) to provide this, but apparently not.

Comment: I meant the keyboard layout inside Windows.  Though come to think of it the Mac layout might also be a factor - depends how VMWare Fusion does the mapping I guess.

Answer (score 1):

found this "" by the using the alt/option key on the right hand side + the "#" key above the enter key

(note: the left hand side alt didn't work for me)

Answer (score 0):

I found this `\` by the using the alt/option key on the right hand side + the `#` key above the enter key
(note: the left hand side alt didn't work for me)

It took me hours but I found it none of the answer here was helpful.